# Filter Characters in an entire data frame with tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

Hello I want to filter the following data frame

[image: table]

```
library(tidyverse)

datclear<-dat %>% filter(!grepl("vacio|--",dat$`question1-NATURALES`))
```

that way i get the following

[image: tabla2]

As you can see, I delete all the name data "vacio" then try to apply the same for all the data now including the data "--", to apply it to everything and remove "--" and try in a similar way to do it for a single column but it was removed exclusively in the column that I chose but not in the entire data frame and try the following code

```
datclear<-dat %>% filter(!grepl("vacio|--",dat))
```

> Error:
> ! Problem with `filter()` input `..1`.

i Input `..1` is `!grepl("vacio|--", dat)`.

x Input `..1` must be of size 710 or 1, not size 102.

Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.

I would like to eliminate the two values ​​for the entire dataframe. I would like you with more experience to help me. I leave the data hosted on google drive below, thanks in advance

[Data_U](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AnlfFCKrOj_7ypXOFAdWJmQB3AkQE-ye/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi - you say "I have the following data frame", but then show a _picture_ of a data frame.  We can't copy and paste this to test and verify solutions. Could you please edit the question to include your data as text, so that your question is reproducible? You might find the function `dput` helpful here.

Comment: @alan Cameron Hello at the end I add the base in the link what dat_U says

Answer (score 0):

Base R. You could start right when you read in the file, if you know that 'vacio' and '--' are really 'NA':

```
dat_U <- read.table('~/Downloads/dat_U.csv', header = TRUE, na.strings=c('vacio','--'), sep = ',')
```

then identify `complete.cases()`:

```
dat_clean <-dat_U[which(complete.cases(dat_U) == TRUE), ]
str(dat_clean)
'data.frame':   335 obs. of  102 variables:
 $ Corr                  : int  11 12 14 15 17 18 19 21 26 28 ...
 $ sector                : chr  "Publico" "Publico" "Publico" "Publico" ...
 $ question1.NATURALES   : chr  "B" "C" "C" "C" ...
 $ question2.NATURALES   : chr  "C" "A" "B" "D" ...
 $ question3.NATURALES   : chr  "B" "D" "C" "A" ...
 $ question4.NATURALES   : chr  "A" "B" "A" "D" ...
 $ question5.NATURALES   : chr  "C" "A" "C" "B" ...
 $ question6.NATURALES   : chr  "D" "D" "C" "D" ...
 $ question7.NATURALES   : chr  "C" "A" "C" "C" ...
<------------------snip---------------------->
```

Comment: Hello, I can't change them, I just want to remove them to get the fashion and then change the "--" for it

Comment: ?fashion?. If you look at `dat_U`, before complete cases, all `vacio` and `--` have been converted to `NA`, not removed, but 'Not available', so you don't do the complete.cases() part. I really depends on what you're doing next.